# boolean indexing to store a column value as a variable in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, variables, import

Let's say I have a CSV file which reads

```
Student_Name Grade
Mary     75
John     65
Stella   90
```

I'd like to store Stella's grade as a variable. 
My current code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
student_grades = pd.read_csv('.../Term2grades.csv')

x = student_grades.loc[student_grades['Student_Name'] == "Stella", ['Grade']]
print(x)
```

The output of this code is:

```
       Grade
2      90
```

However, I only want to get 90 so that I can use it later (if x > 85 etc.)
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the underlying numpy array and take its first element (assuming you have a single element):

```
student_grades.loc[student_grades['Student_Name'] == "Stella", 'Grade'].values[0]
Out: 90
```

You can also use `iat` or `iloc`  on the returning Series:

```
student_grades.loc[student_grades['Student_Name'] == "Stella", 'Grade'].iloc[0]
Out: 90
```

Comment: That works! Would it still work if I had a file of 500+ students? What does the 0 in values[0] do?

Comment: @memothetaker The `student_grades['Student_Name'] == "Stella"` part is boolean indexing. We don't know how many rows it would return, so it returns a Series. That Series can be empty, it might have a single element or it might have several elements. When it has a single element, you need to access that element by its position (0). You can have 500+ students, as long as the student name is unique, it is guaranteed to work. If none of the students has that name, it will return a key error. If several of them have the same name, it will return the first one only.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot!